# Android linphone prepare_sources.sh

Tags: android, ip, call, sip

I am trying to compile linphone for android but I'm but I can't manage to pass throw prepare_sources.sh.
I have installed all dependencies and download ndk. Is there a way to install ndk? I didn't found it!
I'm working in Ubuntu 10.11. 
The output I get when I execute prepare_sources.sh is:

```
Applying patch to ffmpeg
patching file submodules/externals/ffmpeg/libavcodec/arm/int_neon.S
Hunk #1 FAILED at 35.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 55.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file submodules/externals/ffmpeg/libavcodec
/arm/int_neon.S.rej
cd: 12: can't cd to /home/glot/git/linphone-android/submodules/libilbc-rfc3951
iLBC prepare stage failed
find: «../../libvpx/»: No existe el archivo o directorio
cp: el destino, «../../libvpx/», no es un directorio
VP8 prepare stage failed.
cd: 16: can't cd to /home/glot/git/linphone-android/submodules/mssilk
SILK audio plugin prepare state failed.
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you still need an answer...

Open your terminal

- make sure you have done this: "git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive" //*the --recursive part is very important
- then do this: apt-get install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config
- go to your project root: cd/home/user/project //wherver your project is
- in your project root: export PATH=/home/user/android-ndk:$PATH //wherever your android-ndk is stored in
- then run ./prepare_sources.sh //in your project root still
- after that do this: /home/user/android-ndk/ndk-build // in your project root too

Answer (score 1):

I work in Mac but I get the same error and I found out that some changes in this file helped me:

```
linphone-android/submodules/externals/libvpx/build/make/gen_asm_deps.sh
```

Line 45, change it to :

```
includes=$(LC_ALL=C egrep -i "include +\"[a-z0-9_/]+\.${sfx}" $srcfile |
```

and do:

---

- Go to root directory of the downloaded project through command: `cd /home/your_downloaded_project_path/`
- Fire the command: `./prepare_sources.sh /home/android-ndk-r7b/`
- Go to root directory of NDK folder through command: `cd /home/android-ndk-r7b/`
- Fire the command: export `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/your_downloaded_project_path/`
- `./ndk_build clean`
- `./ndk_build -i`

Hope it helps.

NB:
I found it from here: https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/forum/#!msg/webm-discuss/OdEWb-rBBhw/_GMux8jTOnoJ